# Lock out part of the code so nobody except the desired developers can modify it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have an angular application that contains a controller that we need to keep "private" so nobody except the developers in charge can actually change that code.

The rest of the team should be able to use that part without being able to modify it, but they should be able to modify the rest of the application.
Do you guys know if there is a way to do that?

EDIT: Using VCS is one possible solution, we use GitHub, I need to find a way of checking that the source is not modified. Sorry for the lack of information in the original question.

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible. JavaScript will always run on the client and you really have no means of preventing modification of the code. Hence the golden rule 'Never trust the client'.

If you are talking about making sure that the code cannot be modified in your version management system that is a different story - in which case you probably want to take a look at a pre-commit hook or something similar.

Comment: Do you want it locked in version control? Locked once it's deployed? I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Or as Jon mentioned locked in the browser? (In which case, he's right, there isn't really anything you can do; you have to do the authentication/authorization checking on the server side)

Comment: @Brian that has nothing to do with the question of OP - please refrain from throwing buzzwords around that have no relation to the question.

Comment: @JonKoops You're right, I misread the question. I assumed it was to prevent clients, not developers, from modifying the application process.

Comment: @JoeFrambach this isn't appropriate for The Workplace.

Comment: It is possible with VCS, but since it isn't even mentioned in the question, it can hardly be considered constructive and should be closed. An example for Git, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

Comment: Sorry guys for the lack of information, I ment using VCS, we use github.

Comment: Look into git submodules, and give per-developer push access to each controller.

Comment: @JoeFrambach person problem questions are poor fit over there, see [What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260). Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with (you even got the site name wrong)